# Color certain cells in devexpress

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I want to color only certain cells of specified columns(Field1 and Field2) of Rows that respect my  conditions. The code bellow colors the right rows, but all the columns(of that rows).

```
 private void gvPriceListManagement_RowCellStyle(object sender, RowCellStyleEventArgs e)
         {
              if (gvPriceListManagement.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "Field1") == DBNull.Value)
              {
               e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
              }
              else if (Convert.ToDecimal(gvPriceListManagement.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "Price")) != Convert.ToDecimal(gvPriceListManagement.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "Field2")))
              {
               e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
              }
         }
```

How can I color only the specified columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To colour only specific cells in the grid, add some additional logic to only colour one column of the row:

```
private void gvPriceListManagement_RowCellStyle(object sender, RowCellStyleEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName = "Field1" && 
            vPriceListManagement.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "Field1") == DBNull.Value)
    {
        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.LightCoral;
    }
    else if (e.Column.FieldName = "Price" && 
        Convert.ToDecimal(gvPriceListManagement.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "Price")) != 
        Convert.ToDecimal(gvPriceListManagement.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, "Field2")) &&)
    {
        e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}
```